# Pairing processes for data exchange as they finish tasks

Tags: mpi

I am developing a program in C using MPI for inter-process message passing. The program has the following structure:

- P processes each perform an iteration of a task;
- Upon completion of an iteration, process p searches for another process q that has also finished its iteration;
- p and q synchronise by exchanging the results of their previous iteration;
- p and q each initiate a new iteration of the task, and so on...

I don't know how to facilitate p and q identifying each other as processes that have finished their respective iterations. Previously, I had implemented a more conventional "global" synchronisation step once all processes had finished their iterations, but I am hoping to obtain a performance increase by implementing the "pairwise" synchronisation above in which processes begin to synchronise as soon as possible after finishing an iteration of the task.

Does anybody know of a way for processes to identify each other as they finish their respective tasks?

Comment: this is a quite uncommon paradigm, and I am afraid the easiest implementation is a centralized one (e.g. each tasks notifies the orchestrator when it is done, and when two tasks are done, the orchestrator notifies both of them to work as a pair. of course this implicitly suggests that even if `p` and `q` have initiated the iteration, one will complete it (way) before the other.

Comment: Is this related to replica exchange molecular dynamics? Anyways, do you care more about latency of detection or minimizing the resources required to achieve this? Is it possible to devote one process to controlling this? Or perhaps insert periodic poll operations in your tasks? I have a bunch of ideas but need to understand the constraints.

Comment: Hi @Jeff. Latency of detection is the priority; devoting one process to coordination is not a problem, and indeed is what I have been experimenting with. Let's say that minimising absolute run time divided by P-1 is the overall objective with this program, with the -1 accounting for the coordinating process. Periodic poll operations is something I am not familiar with. For reference, the algorithm that I am trying to implement is Algorithm 3 on page 4 of (http://papers.nips.cc/paper/3524-asynchronous-distributed-learning-of-topic-models.pdf) - HDP topic modelling as applied to text data.

Comment: `int flag; MPI_Iprobe(MPI_ANY_SOURCE, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &flag, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);` is the portable way to cause the MPI library to enter the progress engine. However, if you are dedicating a process to bookkeeping here, then you don't need that, as you can just do a blocking Probe or Recv to wait on control messages.